# Reading the next line of a file only once

Tags: c#, .net, file, streamreader

I have an application that reads information from a text file and then categorizes them and puts them onto a Database. For one category, I need to check the line that comes right after the current line and look for a certain keyword?

How do i get to read this line? This should happen when the streamreader has the current line already open....

I'm using c# on VS2010.

*Edit*:

All of the code below is in a ***while (!sReader.EndOfStream)*** loop

```
 string line = sReader.ReadLine(); //Note: this is used way above and lots of things are done before we come to this loop

 for (int i = 0; i < filter_length; i++)
 {
       if (searchpattern_queries[i].IsMatch(line) == true)
       {
               logmessagtype = selected_queries[i];

               //*Here i need to add a if condition to check if the type is "RESTARTS" and i need to get the next line to do more classification. I need to get that line only to classify the current one. So, I'd want it to be open independently *

               hit = 1;
               if (logmessagtype == "AL-UNDEF")
               {
                   string alid = AlarmID_Search(line);
                   string query = "SELECT Severity from Alarms WHERE ALID like '" +alid +"'";
                   OleDbCommand cmdo = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
                   OleDbDataReader reader;
                   reader = cmdo.ExecuteReader();
                   while (reader.Read())
                   {
                        if (reader.GetString(0).ToString() == null)
                        { }
                        else
                        {
                             string severity = reader.GetString(0).ToString();
                             if (severity == "1")
                                 //Keeps going on.....
```

Also, the .log files that are opened might go upto 50 Mb types... ! Which is why i dont really prefer reading all lines and keeping track!

Comment: StreamReader does not "have a line open".

Comment: Can't you just call `StreamReader.ReadLine()` ?

Comment: @Bryan: Wouldnt that just move to that line? I need that line to be read again for the next iteration..

Comment: techmanc  it sounds like an easy problem to solve if you give an outline. Now it require a lot of guessing and assuming. Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Simplest method is to use : Read all lines and check for i+1... worked for me.. :) Thanks everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use

```
 string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
```

and process the file with a `for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i ++)` loop.

For a big file, simply cache the 'previous line' or do an out-of-band ReadLine().

Answer (score 5):

Here is an idiom to process the current line you while having the next line already available:

```
public void ProcessFile(string filename)
{
    string line = null;
    string nextLine = null;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        nextLine = reader.ReadLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            // Process line (possibly using nextLine).

            line = nextLine;
            nextLine = reader.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is basically a **queue** with a maximum of two items in it, or "one line read-ahead".

**Edit:** Simplified.

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just call `reader.ReadLine()` again? Or is the problem that you then need to use the line in the next iteration of the loop?

If it's a reasonably small file, have you considered reading the whole file using `File.ReadAllLines()`? That would probably make it simpler, although obviously a little less clean in other ways, and more memory-hungry for large files.

EDIT: Here's some code as an alternative:

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(filename))
{
    string line = null; // Need to read to start with

    while (true)
    {
        if (line == null)
        {
            line = reader.ReadLine();
            // Check for end of file...
            if (line == null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (line.Contains("Magic category"))
        {
            string lastLine = line;
            line = reader.ReadLine(); // Won't read again next iteration
        }
        else
        {
            // Process line as normal...
            line = null; // Need to read again next time
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the line for the next iteration. I just need it as a reference to classify the current line.. Is there any way where I can open the line isolated from the current readline... I thought about reading all lines.. but there are cases where the file is enormous... and it wouldnt be ideal !

Comment: @techmanc: How big is "enormous" exactly? You could always keep a copy of the line you read - the tricky bit is making sure you use that instead of reading the next line.

Comment: I read 100 files and put them into a DB for one iteration. And some files are some 50-100 MB possibly!

Comment: @techmanc: Well that's not *so* much really - if it makes the code simpler, I'd be tempted to read each file in completely to process it. I'll give some code as an alternative though...

Answer (score 0):

You could save the position of the stream then after calling ReadLine, seek back to that position. However this is pretty inefficient.

I would store the result of ReadLine into a "buffer", and when possible use that buffer as a source. When it is empty, use ReadLine.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really a file IO expert... but why not do something like this:

Before you start reading lines declare two variables.

```
string currentLine = string.Empty
string previousLine = string.Empty
```

Then while you are reading...

```
previousLine = currentLine;
currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
```